# Why does vim highlight this file differently?

Tags: vim

#### Note

I am using the local vim plugin that allows me to use a project-specific .vimrc file, in general it works fine and as you'd expect.

#### Background

I work with Silverstripe, and therefore have to work with Silverstripe templates, which are *.ss files, however by default vim assigns *.ss to scheme files. Now I only use Silverstripe for one project, and have been using the html filetype set in my project-specific .vimrc for highlighting, however after encountering a few bugs, I figured that I would add the highlighting for *.ss files in an htmlss.vim file (using html.vim as a base, i just added the template rules near the end). After a bit of trial and error I got it working and highlighting properly, however i have encountered a strange bug...

#### Question

Using this project .vimrc:

```
augroup filetypedetect
    autocmd! * *.ss
    autocmd! BufEnter *.ss setf htmlss
augroup END
```

Everything works fine, however, using this .vimrc:

```
augroup filetypedetect
    autocmd! * *.ss
    autocmd! BufEnter,BufRead,BufNewFile *.ss setf htmlss
augroup END
```

The syntax highlighting fails, it sets the filetype correctly, but the highlighting goes screwy.

I guess I want to know why version 1 works, but version 2 doesn't, despite nothing else changing.

Addendum

After a little more investigation, i have found that removing `autocmd! * *.ss` makes the second one work, only if i remove `!` from the `autocmd! BufEnter,BufRead,BufNewFile *.ss setf htmlss`. i.e.

```
augroup filetypedetect
    autocmd BufEnter,BufRead,BufNewFile *.ss setf htmlss
augroup END
```

works but

```
augroup filetypedetect
    autocmd! BufEnter,BufRead,BufNewFile *.ss setf htmlss
augroup END
```

and

```
augroup filetypedetect
    autocmd! * *.ss
    autocmd BufEnter,BufRead,BufNewFile *.ss setf htmlss
augroup END
```

do not.

Again, my question is why these difference occur, i have a working implementation now, so i am not interested in any investigation. I don't want solutions as i have no problem.

Comment: Are you setting the color scheme, or any highlighting options with autocmd commands? Try removing the ! mark from the second autocmd! statement and see what happens...

Comment: @Filip It should not make a difference. I would suggest completely removing first `:autocmd!` instead (because I do not see why is it needed, not because it should interfere), doing `debug edit /path/to/file.ss` and trying to track down a problem.

Comment: Alternatively, do `set verbosefile=verbose.log verbose=15 | edit /path/to/file.ss | set verbose=0` first with first working variant and then with a second one (with different name after `verbosefile=`) and then doing a `vimdiff` against those two.

Comment: My problem is not that it doesn't work, I am interested in why one works and the other does not. This isn't a "I have a problem" question, more a "I am curious about this behavior" question. I don't have the time to track down the reason myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably caused by your syntax file conflicting with itself when applied multiple times. One of the first lines in the syntax file is probably `syntax enable`, which enables syntax without changing any of the current highlight settings. Per [the docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html):

> ```
> The ":syntax enable" command will keep your current color settings.  This
> allows using ":highlight" commands to set your preferred colors before or
> after using this command.  If you want Vim to overrule your settings with the
> defaults, use:
>         :syntax on
> ```

So, an adequate "solution" should be to change `syntax enable` to `syntax on` in the syntax file.